# How to make a counter that adds a specific number per second using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, counter

i have the following code, which should add 2.6 every second. But after the first add i get 8.
How can I fix this? On the tester here it works but on my page i get 8 https://260044-5.web1.fh-htwchur.ch/

Thanks in advance.

```js
setTimeout(start, 0000);
var i = 2.6;
var num = document.getElementById('humans');

function start() {
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
    if (i < 100000000) {
      i += 2.6;
      num.innerText = Math.round(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="humans">2.6</div>
<p>Menschen wurden geboren.</p>
```

Comment: Make this ```num.innerText = Math.round(i);``` to ```num.innerText = i;```

Comment: What's the purpose of `Math.round()` if you want to add floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. The main problem was your rounding off, you basically used `Math.round()` but yet you are dealing with a floating point data type. So just use `YourNumber.toFixed(n)` where `n` is the number of decimal points you want to show. You can check below. I just made your code shorter and brief but you can basically change the rounding off on your code and it should work..

```js
setTimeout((function(){
  var i = 2.6;
  return function start() {
    setInterval(()=> {
      if (i < 100000000){
        i += 2.6;
        document.getElementById('humans').innerText = i.toFixed(1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
})(), 0000);
```

```html
<div id="humans">2.6</div>
<p>Menschen wurden geboren.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're rounding the value when setting the text:

```
num.innerText = Math.round(i);
```

If you want to show the value to the n'th decimal just use `toFixed`.
Example:

```
num.innerText = i.toFixed(1); /* will give you one number after the decimal point */
```

Answer (score 0):

The code here it works, but in the link you posted, you have that in your script:

```
//funtion for humans born

setTimeout(start, 0000);
var i = 2.6;
var num = document.getElementById('humans');

function start() {
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
    if (i < 100000000) {
      i += 2.6;
      num.innerText = Math.round(i);
    }
}

//funtion for trees cut

setTimeout(start, 0000);
var t = 475.646879756;
var t = document.getElementById('trees');

function startTwo() {
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}
```

You're executing `start` twice: one after "humans born" and the other after "trees cut".

Therefore you have two concurrent interval that execute `increase` twice every second, and each of the `increase` call is manipulating the same variables. That's why you got 8 immediately.

I'm not sure what's your goal here, but you either have different variables / function to increase every second for "humans born" and "trees cut", or you have one `start` call (and therefore one `increase` function called every second).

Anyhow, this is your mistake: if you want to clarify your logic; I / we can help further.